# How to fully remove partition made by local host remove host and all that had been put on drive? Hacked my Mac. Need help asap I

Tags: sudo, macos, kill, hosts

So I opened my Mac and noticed a random guests account made due to my kids father previously hacking an older laptop and it not being usable I knew immediately to check logs. After some digging I came across some codes entered into Mac using launchd+202435[B402F91-45AB-3275-AC3C-E9F651f3a32]:
??
Also seeing passd as a running application which is connected and just so much he did on This.  This issome of the code I see put in to big the whole system so even when I restore to normal Mac settings and erase due to the disc partition made it will not remove this file/user or host made/application idk this is insane I’m seeing also ask module: com.Apple.networking.boringssl
Local host syslogd[43] it’s made a guide partition scheme and physical store disk and using the codes to remove volume is not working. I’m new to all of this and just cannot afford to bring to a store this is second time he did this but luckily not much was on it when he did . I hope. How do I just kill this all. I was able to get into the sudo nano text edit however from there I cannot type under the text to change anything it only will type above the text .

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Unfortunately this is very unclear. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742259/edit) your question and try to explain your problem like you would to someone who has absolutely no idea about your environment, your operating system version, what problems exactly you see there etc. - because we don't. Leave out everything not directly related to the problem ("idk this is insane" etc...). As this is caused by your kids' father maybe you could ask him to undo whatever he's done to your system? And of course ensure he can't access it again.